# Delete the elements for given number of iterations

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of `N` integers. Traverse the whole array and select K positions that contain the same values. These selected `K` are then deleted from the array. If we cannot select `K` values, then no places can be deleted from the array.

The task is to minimize the numbers of distinct integers in the array available after each iteration.

For a given `Q` queries, with each query with a number `P`. For each query, print the number of distinct integers present in the array after doing `P` iterations.

```
1<= N <= 10^6
1<= K <= 10
1<= Q <= 10^5
0<= C <= 10^5
1 <= P <= N

Example:
N=5
K=1
Q=3

Array = [5,0,1,2,1];

Queries (Various P values):
1
5
3

Output:
3
0
1
```

**Explanation when P = 3:**

```
1. First iteration, we can remove element 1 with value `5`.
2. Second iteration, we can remove element 2 with `0`.
3. Third iteration, we can remove element 4 with value `2`.
```

Finally array contains only two elements with values `1`. **So number of distinct colors remaining is 1.**

This is the code I tried but got stuck on how to meet the requirements:

```
static int getDistinctFeatures(int[] array, int size, int K, int P) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    // Count the occurrence of each element in the array
    for (int i : array) {
        map.put(i, map.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
    }

    Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
    List<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<>(keys);

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < P && index < keyList.size(); i++) {
        int key = keyList.get(index);
        index++;
        int count = map.get(key);
        if (count == 1) {
            map.remove(key);
        } else {
            // What to do here
        }
    }
    return map.size();
}
```

Comment: So if k=2 and Array=[1,1,1,3,3,3], What will the answer for p=1? Is it 2?

Comment: @mahbubcseju, i'm also not sure for this input, the exam gave only 3 sample inputs. I was trying to solve for those first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggested approach.

1. Construct a map from `value` to `count_of_value`
2. Find out how many values have counts NOT divisible by `k`.  This `count_incommensurate` is how many values you can't get rid of.
3. For the remaining values, create an array of, by ascending counts, `count_of_value / k`.
4. Now create a lookup of, by number of iterations, how many deletable values there are.
5. Perform your lookups.

In your case these steps result in the following.  The initial map is:

```
{
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 1,
    5: 1,
}
```

All of the values of divisible by `k=1` so `count_incommensurate = 0`.

The array of counts in increasing order is `[1, 1, 1, 2]`.

Now we come to the lookup array.  It starts at `0` with the total number of counts, which is `4`.  So `[4, ...`.  Now we write each number the count number of times before decreasing, and stop at 0.  So we get `[4, 3, 2, 1, 1]`.  In other words

```
counts: [1, 1, 1, 2   ]
lookup: [4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

If our counts had been `[1, 2, 3]` we would have instead gotten

```
counts: [1, 2   , 3      ]
lookup: [3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

But back to what we actually got.  `[4, 3, 2, 1, 1]` is a 0-based array for our lookups, and everything off the end is `0`.

Now do our lookups.

Lookup `1` plus incommensurate gives us `3 + 0 = 3`.

Lookup `5` is off the end so we get `0 + 0 = 0`.

Lookup `3` gives us `1 + 0 = 1`.

If we repeated this exercise with `k=2` we'd find that `count_incommensurate` is `3` and our lookup array winds up being `[1]`.  (After zero iterations, the element `1` is still there.)  Since all the lookups are off the end, we'd get `3, 3, 3` as our answer.

The time for this algorithm is `O(N + Q)`.  Given that it takes `O(N)` to scan the values, and `O(Q)` to scan the queries, you can't really improve on that by more than a constant factor. A small point to be mentioned is that the initial array of counts (`[1, 2, 1, 1]` in this case) needs to be sorted, which adds a time complexity of `O(N log N)` to the problem.

Comment: How the array `[4, 3, 2, 1, 1]` is generated, can you please explain. Also I lost and not able to understand the explanation below the statement `The lookup array is (remember it is a 0-based array) [4, 3, 2, 1, 1]` how the lookups 1, 5, 3 are done and why we are adding them to incommensurate

Comment: What I mean is, I was not able to understand how the points 4 & 5 are implemented

Comment: @learner I added more explanation of how they were done in this case, and how they would have been different if we had a different array of counts.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: As for why we add incommensurate, that is because we NEVER get rid of any of the incommensurate elements.  We try to remove them, but eventually we wind up with a remainder below `k` that we can't delete.  So we are tracking how many elements we can get rid of, how quickly, and adding how many we take the last one of.

Comment: @btilly Can you please the code here I am getting missed while reading your explanation.

Comment: @thealchemist Sorry, I make it a personal policy to NOT post code for anything that looks like it comes from an online judge type of thing.

Comment: Didn't know it's coming from an online judge.

Comment: @thealchemist I don't know that it is either.  But the format of the question, including the parameters you might encounter, looks like it does.

Comment: Suggested addition from [Lycanthropeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12661027/lycanthropeus): *A small point to be mentioned is that the initial array of counts (`[1, 2, 1, 1]` in this case) needs to be sorted, which adds a time complexity of O(N log N)` to the problem.* (me: I didn't like *needs to be*, but now checked your suggestion reads `array of counts in increasing order` - Lycanthropeus may well be right about runtime growth assessment.)

Comment: @greybeard Each time you select `k` of the same value and delete them.  If a value appears a number of times not divisible by `k`, you can't ever delete its last copy and therefore can't remove that value from the array.  And Lycanthropeus missed something important.  The counts are in the range `1..N`, and there can be at most `O(sqrt(N))` distinct counts.  A bucket sort will sort that in `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I coded based on the algorithm suggested by @btilly.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;


class Main {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
           
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        String[] num_arr;
        num_arr = br.readLine().split("\\s");
        
        int [] nkq_arr = new int[3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   
            nkq_arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(num_arr[i]);
        }

        int N = nkq_arr[0];
        int K = nkq_arr[1];
        int Q = nkq_arr[2];
        
        int i = 0,j = 0;

        String[] param_arr;
        param_arr = br.readLine().split("\\s");
        
        int [] arr = new int[N];
        while(i < N)
        {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(param_arr[i]);
            i++;
        }

        int[] queries = new int[Q];
        while(j < Q)
        {
            queries[j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            j++;
        }

        for(int c=0;c<Q;c++)
        {
          System.out.println(minFeatures(arr,N,K,queries[c]));
        } 

    }
    static int minFeatures (int [] arr, int N, int K, int query)
    {
      HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
      int count=0;
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
        if(!map.containsKey(arr[i]))
        {
          map.put(arr[i],1);
          count++;
        }
        else
        {
          Integer b = map.get(arr[i]);
          b+=1;
          map.replace((Integer)arr[i],b);
        }
      }
      
      List<Integer> relevant_arr = new ArrayList();
      int improper_count=0;
      int relevant_arr_length = 0;

      for(Integer val : map.values())
      {
        if(val%K==0)
        {
          relevant_arr.add(val/K);
          relevant_arr_length++;
        }
        else
        {
          improper_count++;
        }
      }
      Collections.sort(relevant_arr);
      List<Integer> lookUp_arr = new ArrayList();

      int alpha = 0;
      int overall_length=0;

      while(alpha < relevant_arr_length)
      {
        int number_of_times = relevant_arr.get(alpha);
        int beta = number_of_times;

        while(beta > 0)
        {
          lookUp_arr.add(count);
          beta--;
          overall_length++;
        }
        count--;
        alpha++;
      }

      
      if(query > overall_length-1)
      {
        return improper_count;
      }      
      else
      {
        return improper_count + lookUp_arr.get(query);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Implementation of algorithm suggested by @btilly.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def evaluateMin(arrQ,k,queryArr):
  ans = []
  countMap = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
  for value in arrQ:
    countMap[value] +=1
  
  counts=[]
  presentEveryTime = 0
  for value in countMap:
    if countMap[value] % k != 0:
      presentEveryTime +=1
    else:
      counts.append(int(countMap[value]/k))

  # Creating Lookup Array
  counts = sorted(counts)
  lookup = []
  # print(counts)
  appender = len(counts)
  for count in counts:
    for i in range(count):
      lookup.append(appender)
    
    if appender != 1:
      appender -=1
  # print(lookup,presentEveryTime)
  for query in queryArr:
    if query >= len(lookup):
      ans.append(0+presentEveryTime)
    else: 
      ans.append(lookup[query]+presentEveryTime)

  return ans

print(evaluateMin([5,0,1,2,1,1,1],2,[1,5,3,0,2]))
```